# Firebase hosting issues

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have a basic node js app using express-jade files. I wanted to deploy it onto my firebase a/c. When I use firebase deploy command, I keep getting :

```
Preparing to deploy Public Directory...
Public Directory Warning - Public directory does not contain an index.html
```

And honestly, I don't have an index.html file coz I am using jade files. I am a newbie in client side related items so any help would be appreciated.

Here's how my fiebase.json file looks like:

```
{
  "firebase": "torrid-heat-237",
  "public": "./findUrTalentsAdmin-master",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Hosting](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/) is a service for hosting static assets, e.g. a static web site. The root of a static web site is normally an index.html page, which the `firebase deploy` command checks for.

[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) (from my quick "research" on the topic) is a node template engine. This means that it runs inside a node.js process. The CDN servers that Firebase Hosting runs on, do not expose a node.js API to your site.

So you cannot run a Jade template powered web site directly on Firebase Hosting. The [Jade command line tool](http://jade-lang.com/command-line/) has commands to convert your Jade templates into regular HTML (e.g. `$ jade < my.jade > my.html`), which you can then deploy to Firebase Hosting.