# Port and Proxy Config on ng-build

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, firebase-hosting

I have a frontend running for example on int.myapp.com and it's backend on int.backend.myapp.com. I thought I can do the proxing with the proxy.config.json like this:

```
 "/api": {
    "target": "https://int.backend.myapp.com",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
```

And in my package.json file

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

Everything works on my dev environment.

But when I build for production :

```
ng build --prod
```

and deploy on firebase

```
firebase deploy
```

The web application is not able to communicate with the API

How can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Firebase Hosting is for hosting static assets (HTML, client-side JS files, images, etc) only. It cannot be used to run node.js scripts (or any other server-side code).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026032/firebase-hosting-issues

Comment: I am going to assume from some context here that this is angular2, and remove the tag for AngularJs, which this question wouldn't apply to.

Comment: I'd like an answer to this as well irrespective of Firebase hosting.  From what I can see thus far, using --proxy-config only seems to be for development.  My research hasn't indicated anything concerning the Angular 2 CLI supporting this kind of proxy config into a PROD-distributable asset that will run node/express or anything on the server to provide this proxy.

Comment: I am trying to figure out something very similar, angular4 app, need proxy setup in production on IIS. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122687/hosting-a-website-in-iis-8-with-proxy-settings

Comment: Franky - did get any solution on this? I also stuck at this point. I build the code using "ng-build" and copied the "dist" folder to apache server. But my rest api's which are configured using "proxy-config" are not working.

Comment: @VijayShegokar i have the same problem did you found any solution for this please ?!

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody else run into this problem, I found a workaround in case you still want to run **locally** your **production angular application,** use the http-server application:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Build your production application:

`ng build --prod`

Go to your dist/[YOUR_APP_NAME_FOLDER] folder:

```
cd dist/[YOUR_APP_NAME_FOLDER]
```

Run the http-server application and pass the Proxy option (--proxy or -P) with the backend proxy you would like to point to:

```
 http-server -c-1 -P http://localhost:3000 .
```

Comment: In my case it was useless

Comment: this isn't practical for the build, the dev-ops pipeline process would infer this is built and passed to the server, not manual.

Answer (score 0):

During deploying your app to production:
Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to index.html. Learn more about server-side redirects here https://angular-doc.ru/guide/deployment#fallback.

Basic deployment to a remote server

For the simplest deployment, create a production build and copy the output directory to a web server.

Start with the production build:

content_copy
ng build --prod
Copy everything within the output folder (dist/ by default) to a folder on the server.

Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to index.html. Learn more about server-side redirects below.

source https://angular-doc.ru/guide/deployment