# Different proxy config based on environment in Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

How can I declare 2 different proxy URLs for development and production environments in Angular 2 CLI project? For example, while in development mode, I would like to use

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

but in production mode, I will use

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://api.exampledomain.com",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside src->environments, there are 2 files; 1 for development and 1 for prod.

Comment: Yes, there are. But for proxy configuration to work, we need to add the above code to a json file. e.g. proxy.config.json. And then this file is invoked via `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json`. So is there a way we can change this based on environment?

Comment: So can't you create 2 different files and point that as the --proxy-config file when running the command?

Comment: I don't think creating the files will solve the problem. Since after production build, I will neither be able to set --proxy-config in the command line nor will  it work. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/40995791/5128818

Comment: Surely when you build an angular app the dist files become a static HTML/JavaScript app and that is copied to a web application server for production.  Hence you only use angular-cli's server in development and not production.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Seems like this would be critical to run inside docker

Comment: why cant you use "fileReplacements" array in angular.json. Wont that work when you change environment??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe you can control the proxy feature through the environment files. An alternative could be to define your api domains in your environment files

```
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    api: 'http://localhost:3000'
};

// environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    api: 'http://api.exampledomain.com'
}
```

then in your ts source files pull the domain from the environment file

```
// some service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environment.ts';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: Http);

    getData(){
        return this.http.get(environment.api + '/rest-of-api');
    }
}
```

now when you run your build or serve commands they will use the api path defined in the environment file

Answer (score 18):

### in fact, you can do it, you just need to configure the router :

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "https://api.exampledomain.com",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "router": {
          "localhost:4200" : "http://localhost:3000/exampledomain",
          "staging.exampledomain.com" : "http://api.staging.exampledomain.com"
        }
    }
}
```

### What this do :

- your url match the proxy => will call the target defined
- the host url match one router configuration => use the new target

### For example :

I've deployed on *localhost:4200* my angular app, when calling the url "api/callMeMaybe", then the router detect it and redirect in "http://localhost:3000/exampledomain".
If I've been on *staging.exampledomain.com* then the redirection will have be to "http://api.stagging.exampledomain.com".
Then, if none match, it keep the original target redirection.

Be careful, as order matters (the 1st match will be take)

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options) with an [example](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#example)

### Edit

You can find the host value on your chrome debugger Network tab and selecting the api call, you get this details : [image: api call header screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could have 2 proxy configurations, `proxy.conf.json` and `proxy.prod.conf.json` and update your `angular.json` file as follow:

```json
"serve": {
  "configurations": {
     "production": {
         "browserTarget": "webapp:build:production",
         "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.prod.conf.json"
      },
      "development": {
         "browserTarget": "webapp:build:development",
         "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

so that the convient proxy configuration is loaded based on current environment