# How to define different environment and run it via Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have two environments, one for staging and another for production. They both have different URLs and I want to build my project using Angular CLI. Right now I have to comment one URL and run another. But I want to control these things directly from the environment file.

I used this way (from [Different proxy config based on environment in Angular 2 CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45525227/3001761)):

```
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    api: 'http://localhost:3000'
};

// environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    api: 'http://api.exampledomain.com'
}
```

Then in your ts source files pull the domain from the environment file:

```
// some service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environment.ts';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: Http);

    getData(){
        return this.http.get(environment.api + '/rest-of-api');
    }
}
```

But in this if I want to  build from production how do I change environment variable value? Because here I import from `environment.ts`, not `environment.prod.ts`.

Comment: See: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Yes i have read this but it does not worked in my case.

Comment: Then show a [mcve] of that. What precisely do you mean by *"not worked"*? I have used this feature, and not had any problems with it.

Comment: How to i define two environment file. So that it will take required file in services

Comment: Exactly the way you have above, as indeed they are set up by the CLI. Read the comments in `environment.ts`. You don't need to change anything in the service, *that's the whole point*.