# Angular Proxy works for GET request but fails POST request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular, proxy

I made a proxy for my requests on my angular app, and I got my GET request to properly redirect to

> http://localhost:3000/api/users

but my POST request still goes to

> http://localhost:4200/api/users

This is my proxy code

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Why does one fail when they're making requests to the same route?

Comment: add / at the last of url i mean  "target": "https://localhost:3000/"

Comment: @Argus I did that but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: why don't you define it in envornment file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525227/different-proxy-config-based-on-environment-in-angular-2-cli

Comment: @Argus when I try that I get a " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error

Comment: its a cors error it means you are making cross domain request so for solution in backend side where your api is called you can make response header set like Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your site url from which you are making request

Comment: @Argus sure, but where would I add this? I only have an api.js file for my server calls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the POST and not the GET because the POST has a body.
The body is redirected to the target.

If you pass the body as it is it won't work, you need to set the body as

JSON.stringify(body)