# Angular 6 - Proxy Config POST request fail with 403

Tags: angular

I'm trying to debug an Angular 6 application and run locally using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`.
My proxy.conf.json file is as follows: (target is obfuscated for security reasons)

```
{
  "/**": {
    "target": "http://my-main-application.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This works for most GET requests but fails for POSTs (see screenshot below). 
[image: search post fail]

Is there something additional I need to do to allow the POSTs to get through successfully?

Comment: Maybe the post requests require some sort of authentication? Thus a 403 is returned.

Comment: @maio290, When the request is sent, Authorization is present under Request Headers

Comment: My answer duplicate of [Get works but Post fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64602072/5335800)

Answer (score 0):

403 is a client side issue, meaning your API gets the call it just refuses to execute it. if your GETs pass, this might be the issue.

[CLI CORS Proxy not changing origin, still get 403 on API reqs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172079/cli-cors-proxy-not-changing-origin-still-get-403-on-api-reqs)

Comment: I saw that other post, but my issue doesn't show OPTIONS. You are correct that the requests never get to the server. Their response is "Invalid CORs Request" - but I'm not sure why this doesn't occur for GETs then.

Comment: A GET doesn't have a content type. If it's a CORS problem a simple way to check if it's only CORS acting up, is trying to send data without any proxy, if the request passes as expected, something else is amiss; if it doesn't, consider checking your data formation and the CORS content type headers.

Comment: Set These two header request.'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, ContentType, contenttype, content-type, Cache-Control, Pragma"

Comment: I tried setting the headers you suggested to no avail. Also, my understanding is that using the proxy conf avoided CORS issues?

Comment: Avoided issues yes, but these issues are a bit in a different nature, read this article for more information: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/overview-of-proxy-server-and-how-we-use-them-in-react-bf67c062b929