# Hosting a Angular 6 app in AWS S3 bucket with proxy

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, serverless-framework

I have an `Angular` App which is calling `API` from different server (CORS) I've set up Proxy to do so.

When I run `npm start` it will run `ng serve --port 80 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

My `package.json` file is as below

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 80 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    -- dependencies --
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    -- devDependencies --
  }
}
```

The `proxy.config.json` file contains `API` endpoint configuration as below.

```
{
    "/api":{
        "target": "http://url_to_my_api_server",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

I've uploaded the project to `AWS` `EC2` (`Ubuntu`, `Node 10.9.0`, `NPM 6.4.0`) Instance and followed [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-6LtzJezsk) tutorial to deploy it using `serverless`. Its created an `S3` bucket and I can access the frontend. `HTML`,`CSS` and `JavaScript` are loading properly, But images are not. If I open the images it's showing `Forbidden 403` error.

Below is my `S3 Bucket` Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Another problem is `API` Requests which I was doing using `Proxy` are also showing the same error.

How to host the website properly on `S3` bucket and make the `API` calls with the `Proxy` (I don't want to disclose the `API` Endpoint to the user).

Is there any other way to host the site?

Comment: where do u have your assets folder on the root path of ur S3 Bucket? Did u edit the bucket rules to public read, also for the assets folder and files?

Comment: Please check the updated question, I've updated the question with `S3 Bucket` policy, I did not check the Assets as its automatically deployed by `serverless`. There are many nested folders in my bucket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proxy.config.json is not working in Angular 4/5 when i use ng build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920937/proxy-config-json-is-not-working-in-angular-4-5-when-i-use-ng-build)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: **S3 bucket gives you option for static web hosting**

1. You need to setup WEBPACK to your project for final build as it is not going to run you npm start script on s3
2. So build your project using webpack.
3. It will bundle your project and gives you 3-4 js file and one html file which is ready deploy on s3
4. In s# property there is option for static web hosting - configure it to provide your landing index.html file
5. that's it your done

Comment: Does it support that Proxy file? `proxy.config.json` is an external file, where all the proxy settings ae saved!

Comment: Hello, I've tried this but now I'm getting `MethodNotAllowed` error. Do I need to set up `CloudFront` and `Labda` to do `API` calls? If yes, then my service is hosted in a different server, why should I set up a gateway to do that?

Comment: @harshil, your answer is missing a key part, the frontend will not be able to make requests to the backend if they are not hosted on the same domain, so in development he uses a proxy, however he is looking for a solution in a production setting where he deploys his app to aws s3.

I didn't know about this problem until today but you totally ignored the error the OP is facing.

Comment: @rakcode I am starting to realize that hosting angular on s3 is not as straightforward as it looks like, also to get around the routing problems in angular I had to specify the origin as my S3 Website DNS instead of just selecting the instance, which might make you lose Caching goodness! so anyway I found a couple of solutions, I haven't tried them yet, but you can check them out in case anyone is facing this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48921029/315625
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60274017/315625